# Javascript update a div

Tags: javascript

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_updates').load('log.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);
```

I have this javascript which is updating a page every 1000ms and I am trying to make so when it loads it should load the div, and also after 1000ms it should load again how do i do that?

so basically dont wait 1000ms until loading it the first time

Answer (score 0):

You can always do:

```
var fun = function () {
    $('#load_updates').load('log.php').fadeIn("slow");
};
var auto_refresh = setInterval(fun, 1000);
fun();
```

Comment: hm, still updates to slow, how "hard" will it run the server if i put it on 100ms?, the log.php only pulls data from database

Comment: The @SoonDead solution is very nice. You can use his solution with the doTimeout plugin: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/delay-poll/

Comment: @mpfasobd I have no idea what happens on your server-side and how, but pulling data from the database can be pretty slow if the database is big, the query is suboptimal or you are pulling a lot of data. Pull less data, optimize your query, and set the timeout to 5 or 10 seconds. 1 seconds is very frequent for UI update.